# Get the data from NSURLSession DownloadTaskWithRequest from completion handler

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

So I'm having hard time understanding something. This are the things I understand about NSURSession :

- Generally , I have 2 options for (as far as I know) **DataTask(e.x dataTaskWithRequest)** And **DownloadTask(e.x DownloadTaskWithRequest**) - Using their delegate method , **or** use the completion handler , Can't do both.
  I have managed to receive DATA using  dataTaskWithRequest like this :

  ```
  let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: dataSourceURL!)
  request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

  let postString = "lastid=\(id)"
  request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
  let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
      data, response, error in

      if error != nil {
          println("error=\(error)")
          return
      }
      if data != nil {
          println("works")
          //Handle data


      }
      //println("response = \(response)")


  }
  task.resume()
  ```

It works perfectly. The problem is that I need to **DOWNLOAD** the data to the disk and not only to the memory(I'm downloading images). So I tried the same with **DownloadTaskWithRequest** + his completion handler and I have noticed that the parameters he takes are the same expect the first one which is **NSURL** and in **DataTaskWithRequest** is **NSData** so it makes things very simpler.
ex.

```
 let task2 = NSURLSession.sharedSession().downloadTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (location : NSURL!, response : NSURLResponse!, error : NSError?) -> Void in
            if error != nil {
                return
            }

            //How do I get the data??
        })
task2.resume()
```

**My Question is this :** I know I can fetch the DATA out of the Location(NSURL) using :

```
    var data = NSData(contentsOfURL: location)
```

1)Will **contentsOfURL** will make another "request" do get this data , or that he is working locally? If it sending request again , how can I avoid it?

2)Is this the right way(I know I can use the delegate methods, I prefer not)?

3)How can I store the data i have downloaded(after questions number 1 and 2 answered) locally , and access it if needed?

Thank you guys!! Sorry for newbie question , I really do care about efficient - Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When using download tasks, generally one would simply use the `location` provided by the `completionHandler` of the download task to simply move the file from its temporary location to a final location of your choosing (e.g. to the Application Support directory, or Documents folder, or Cache folder, or whatever) using `FileManager`.

```swift
let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { location, response, error in
    guard let location, error == nil else {
        print(error ?? URLError(.unknown))
        return
    }

    do {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let fileURL = try fileManager
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
            .appending(path: "test.jpg")
        try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

Or from Swift concurrency (i.e., `async`-`await`):

```swift
let (location, _) = try await URLSession.shared.download(from: url)
let fileManager = FileManager.default
let fileURL = try fileManager
    .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    .appending(path: "test.jpg")
try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: fileURL)
```

You certainly could also load the object into a `Data` using `contentsOf`. Yes, it works with local resources. And, no, it won't make another request ... if you look at the URL it is a file URL in your local file system. But you lose much of the memory savings of download tasks that way, so you might use a data task if you really wanted to get it into a `Data`. But if you wanted to move it to persistent storage, the above pattern probably makes sense, avoiding using a `Data` object altogether.

Comment: Rob, Honestly i would give everything for your knowledge on NSURLSession :D , The problem is that for better user experience i wanted to save files(images only) locally , so if the users exit and open it again it wont re-download it. Can you explain me about the difference between Documents or Cache folder when it comes to efficiency ? And how can i access the data later and load it to e.g image view? thanks!!

Comment: Documents vs Cache folder doesn't matter re efficiency. See [File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html) for discussion of Documents vs Cache (former is for user files that are backed up; latter is for resources that can be removed if the device runs low in storage and is only for resources that can be re-retrieved). The key is that if you avoid `NSData` with your download tasks, you'll ensure a smaller memory footprint while the app is running.

Comment: But is it possible to load imageview with file from document directory? Can you show an example? If i understand you correctly, when i download the images you save then as a file at certain path?

Comment: Sure, you can use `UIImage(contentsOfFile:)` (or if using `NSURL`, use `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` with the file URL, and then `UIImage(data:)` to then load the `image` property of `UIImageView`).

Comment: Rob, im sorry i havent replied i was a at work (im a waiter lol) , Thanks for your awesome replies , i will read them try to get most of them and hit you if i have a problem . :D

Comment: Rob, does this line :         let fileURL = documents.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.jpg")
changes the name of the file after i download it? because i want to rename the files after i download it , and it dosent seems workings ,, let me know , thanks!

Comment: No, you can rename it during this move process. If the rename failed and you implemented it like I have above (where I println the error), it should print an error message. What error did it print? By the way, if you're putting it in a subdirectory, make sure to create that subdirectory first.

Comment: @Rob thanks for yet another informative answer. don't you also need to check for whether error != nil? it seems this only prints an error if location is missing?

Comment: Yeah, but in practice, if the request failed for any reason, `location` is `nil`. But it's prudent to check for both and have revised answer accordingly.